# Align names of figures in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf, latex3

I want to align the name of "Abbildung 1" with the title "Abbildungsverzeichnis" and if the name of the picture is big the rest of the text should be under the name of the picture (aligned with the start of the name of the picture).

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand\ncoverline[1]{\mkern1mu\overline{\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1mu}\mkern1mu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={160mm,235mm},left=25mm, top=35mm,}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\cfoot{}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Para poder insertar gráficos

\usepackage{appendix} % Para agregar un apéndice como capítulo

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Referencias.bib}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for sections


\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=it}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{float}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}
\setlength\cfttabnumwidth{2cm}% Prevent 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
{\bfseries\Large Cover page \par}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\scshape\Large blah \par}
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
{\justify\textbf\scshape\Large\textbf{Erklärung}\par}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\justify blah\par}
\vspace{2.1 cm}
{\justify blah}\hfill
\textit{\rule[-2pt]{5.85cm}{1pt}\\}
\raggedleft{author}
\newpage



\pagenumbering{Roman}
\raggedright
\tableofcontents
\newpage

{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}

\newpage

\listoftables

\newpage

\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listingverzeichnis}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage



\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\markboth{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}{}
\begin{acronym}[LayerNorm]
\acro{NP-hard}{Non-deterministic Polynomial-time hardness}

\acro{LayerNorm}{Layer Normalization}

\end{acronym}
\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Einleitung und Zielsetzung}
\vspace{15pt}
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Imagenes/interaction.png}
\captionof{figure}{Das Grundszenario des Reinforcement Learning in Anlehnung an \cite{algrlcsaba}}
\label{interactionagentenv}
\end{center}
\section{Grundlagen und Stand der Forschung}

\clearpage
\printbibliography[title = {\scshape Literaturverzeichnis},heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

My list of figures look like this:

[image: Index Figures]

I want to see my list of figures like this:

[image]

I will apreciate all your help!

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example that replicates your problem and that others can copy and test as is. Here we don;t even know which document class you're using/

Comment: I am sorry I will add it.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, just in case someone have the same problem, this lines should be added before \begin{document} and inside just only call \listoffigures

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}
\setlength\cftfignumwidth{2.7cm}
```