# Add the name "table" in List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I am a newbie with latex and I would like to see in the list of tables:
"Tabelle 1: Performance-Vergleich mit Ranked Reward (RR) ...................13"

I only declared:

```
\listoftables
```

I have this list of table:

[image: list of tables]

What I need is this:

[image]

The difference is the "Tabelle 1: ......"

I would appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tocloft` package and modify the display as follows (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168918/list-of-tables-customization))

```latex
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}% Use the name used for the tables as prefix
\setlength\cfttabnumwidth{5cm}% Prevent the title from overlapping the "Tabelle X" prefix
```

Probably the length of the `\tablename~` could be automatically used for the `\setlength` as an improvement

Comment: Thanks It worked out but I would like to see the name "Tabelle ...." aligned with the title "Tabellenverzeichnis". Do you know what command should I use?

Comment: Could you please help me with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656982/align-names-of-figures-in-list-of-figures 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm}` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168918/list-of-tables-customization) does that

You probably should mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Thank you! Now It looks as I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the numbering before the caption in the table of contents removed.
Using [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097637/14756734) the numbering will be removed

The MWE below clarifies it

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetable}{}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\makeatother

\listoftables


\begin{table}[htpb]
 \caption[Tabelle 1: Performance-Vergleich mit Ranked Reward (RR)]{Caption above the table }
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{c  c}
 First & Table \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htpb]
 \caption[Caption in the list of tables second example ]{Caption above the table second example}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{c  c}
Second & Table \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to see this: 
Tabellenverzeichnis

Tabelle 1: Performance-Vergleich mit Ranked Reward(RR) .......................1

Comment: Manually typing `Tabelle 1` means that you have not found the right way to do things.  If you change the ordering of the tables, it will become a very confusing table of contents.